# "For both X and Y" or "both for X and Y" or ...?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-order, determiners

Which of these forms is correct?

> - X will be used both for Y and Z
> - X will be used for both Y and Z
> - X will be used both for Y and for Z
> - Other...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As NOAD say: "*When **both** is used in construction with **and**, the structures following 'both' and 'and' should be symmetrical in well-formed English.*"

In the first example, the symmetry or parallelism of 'for Y' and 'for Z' has been lost.

The second and the third example are well-formed English.

Answer (score 9):

All three are acceptable and in use.  The form that is selected might vary, depending on what X, Y, and Z are, how the sentence is punctuated, what verb is in the sentence, and what preposition is used (other prepositions could be used, besides *for*, such as *to*, *by*, or *on*).

> "*In the case of fixed capital, 1973-78 growth rates are close to
>   1973-76 rates both for total capital input and capital input per
>   person potentially employed*." (E.F. Denison) `X both for Y and Z`
>
> "*At the primary level a higher proportion of female teachers means
>   more enrollment and less failure for both boys and girls*." (S.R.
>   Khandker) `X for both Y and Z`
>
> "*...meetings, and paper work, as well as significant expenses both
>   for the initial incorporation and for any ultimate dissolution.*" (T.
>   Crawford) `X both for Y and for Z`